# MySQL format specifier for time zone

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to input some timestamps into a MySQL db in the following format: Sun May 26 23:57:58 CEST 2013

I was thinking of using STR_TO_DATE but am not sure how to deal with the time zone in the timestamp, as I can't find the correct format specifier. At the moment I get stuck with the following:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Sun May 26 23:57:58 CEST 2013','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s');
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be to NOT use your own format for storing timestamp information into MySQL and instead, use the MySQL Datetime/Timestamp format. it is going to make your life much easier down the road when you try to actually query against that data.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the answer. I'm happy to use the MySQL timestamp format, but I'm struggling to get the data into that format in the first place. I've got a php script transferring the data to the db, but I can't alter the format of the source data...

Comment: I am still not clear with the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concated the timezone if you are sure that time you have entered is required timezone

```
SELECT concat(STR_TO_DATE('Sun May 26 23:57:58 CEST 2013','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s') ,' ',@@system_time_zone);
```

OUTPUT

```
0000-05-26 23:57:58 CEST
```

I below I have converted your timezone with required time zone .

```
SELECT concat(date_format(convert_tz('Sun May 26 23:57:58 CEST 2013','+00:00','+10:00'),'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s') ,' ',@@system_time_zone);
```

OUTPUT

```
0000-05-26 23:57:58 CEST
```